# Kendo-UI DropDownListFor - selected index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to change standard dropdown list to the one from kendo and and I've got a problem with getting appropriate selected value.
This code gives me a dropdown list with correct values, but doesn't give selected value (first one is selected).

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryName)              
        .BindTo(Model.AllCountries)                     
        .OptionLabel("-- Select country --")               
    )
```

Inside span (generated by kendo) with this dropdown I found input (type = text) with all values as options, and this input has correct value.
How to display this value in my kendo dropdown?
Thanks

Comment: Even if I add .Value("SomeCountry"), I still get first item selected.

Comment: Can you post your Model?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the name of the `DropDownList` equal to the name of the property in your model?  The [Kendo Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/troubleshooting#widget%27s-value-is-not-bound-to-the-model%27s-property) suggests that "if widget's name is different than the Model's property then the ModelBinder will not be able to update the model."

Comment: I used standard dropdown list helper from MVC and styled it. Drop down from kendo wasn't necessary in this case. I wanted to use id because it looks pretty well, but I couldn't spend too much time on this. Thanks for answers.